# gateway timeout error "The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server or application."

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, gateway

I'm getting an error of "gateway timeout. The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server or application." What I'm doing is I'm getting data from sticky CRM by API and storing it into my database and it takes much time to execute. What I noticed is that I'm getting this error right after one minute. So I want to increase that time. I have install web server under ec2 instance and database under rds. I want to increase my gateway time from one minute to infinite or 15-20 minutes.

Help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You should probably reply immediately to the request, create a job that gets the data from the CRM API, and then provide an API method that can see if new data has arrived.

Comment: are you using a load balancer? Also since you tagged this with laravel I 100% agree with @Snapey that you need to be using a queue for these sort of jobs

Comment: @Snapey I think there will be no need for that as function will be run on backend by cron job. The issue I need to increase the time limit from one minute to maximum so can be avoid gateway timeout error.

Comment: @apokryfos No, I'm not using load balancer. I created rds for database and ec2 for webserver.

Comment: You cannot just wait longer if it is the service you are calling that is issuing the timeout.  If you are issuing the request to your own server and then it is making the API call on your behalf then it could be your side that is timing out not the API

Comment: @Snapey yeah this is from my end. I mean AWS server config issue. What I'm doing suppose there are 1000 of records of specific date in my sticky account and I want to grab all data and to store it in my database. When API call it grab the data of some records suppose 700 in one minute and store it into my database. Everything is working fine and data is storing into my database as well (NOT ALL DATA). The main problem is right after one minute API calls stop and got an error from server of gateway timeout. I need to increase that time in AWS server by somehow.

Comment: how are you initiating this script that collects from the API ?

Comment: @Snapey can you please help me regarding AWS to increase execution time?

Comment: I'm trying, but you did not answer my question

Comment: @Snapey Its simple script getting data from sticky CRM and add records into my database. Please take a look at below piece of code in link:
Link:  https://ibb.co/vqmtPzC

Comment: *how* are you initiating this script that collects from the API ?  (again)  Console command, controller code, queued job ? etc etc

Comment: In controller function I'm initiating all.

Comment: Finally.  So the gateway timeout is between your client and your server and not with the API.  The AWS gateway gives up waiting for the response from YOUR server. - not the process contacting the CRM

Comment: Yeah exactly, so can you help you to increase execution timeout from one minute to more in AWS server?

Comment: No http client should wait more than 1 minute for a response from the server.  Please refer to the very first comment on this thread

Comment: I make some r&d about it get to know just to update line Timeout=300 in your /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file. When I visit that file I'm unable to find Timeout like word there. Can you help me regarding that please?

Comment: Issue has been solved by just adding Timeout 300 in my /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file.